# Where can I get a list of Ansible pre-defined variables?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I see that Ansible provide some pre-defined variables that we can use in playbooks and template files. For example, the host IP address is `ansible_eth0.ipv4.address`. Googleing and searching the docs I couldn't find a list of all available variables.
Would someone list them for me?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-see-a-list-of-all-of-the-ansible-variables):

> ### How do I see a list of all of the ansible_ variables?
>
> Ansible by default gathers “facts” about the machines under management, and these facts can be accessed in playbooks and in templates. To see a list of all of the facts that are available about a machine, you can run the `setup` module as an ad hoc action:
>
> ```
> ansible -m setup hostname
> ```
>
> This will print out a dictionary of all of the facts that are available for that particular host. You might want to pipe the output to a pager.This does NOT include inventory variables or internal ‘magic’ variables. See the next question if you need more than just ‘facts’.

Here is the output for my vagrant virtual machine called `scdev`:

```
scdev | success >> {
    "ansible_facts": {                                                                                                 
        "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [                                                                                
            "10.0.2.15",                                                                                               
            "192.168.10.10"                                                                                            
        ],                                                                                                             
        "ansible_all_ipv6_addresses": [                                                                                
            "fe80::a00:27ff:fe12:9698",                                                                                
            "fe80::a00:27ff:fe74:1330"                                                                                 
        ],                                                                                                             
        "ansible_architecture": "i386",                                                                                
        "ansible_bios_date": "12/01/2006",                                                                             
        "ansible_bios_version": "VirtualBox",                                                                          
        "ansible_cmdline": {                                                                                           
            "BOOT_IMAGE": "/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae",                                                             
            "quiet": true,                                                                                             
            "ro": true,                                                                                                
            "root": "/dev/mapper/precise32-root"                                                                       
        },                                                                                                             
        "ansible_date_time": {                                                                                         
            "date": "2013-09-17",                                                                                      
            "day": "17",                                                                                               
            "epoch": "1379378304",                                                                                     
            "hour": "00",                                                                                              
            "iso8601": "2013-09-17T00:38:24Z",                                                                         
            "iso8601_micro": "2013-09-17T00:38:24.425092Z",                                                            
            "minute": "38",                                                                                            
            "month": "09",                                                                                             
            "second": "24",                                                                                            
            "time": "00:38:24",                                                                                        
            "tz": "UTC",                                                                                               
            "year": "2013"                                                                                             
        },                                                                                                             
        "ansible_default_ipv4": {                                                                                      
            "address": "10.0.2.15",                                                                                    
            "alias": "eth0",                                                                                           
            "gateway": "10.0.2.2",                                                                                     
            "interface": "eth0",                                                                                       
            "macaddress": "08:00:27:12:96:98",                                                                         
            "mtu": 1500,                                                                                               
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0",                                                                                
            "network": "10.0.2.0",                                                                                     
            "type": "ether"                                                                                            
        },                                                                                                             
        "ansible_default_ipv6": {},                                                                                    
        "ansible_devices": {                                                                                           
            "sda": {                                                                                                   
                "holders": [],                                                                                         
                "host": "SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)",                                                                                                                
                "model": "VBOX HARDDISK",                                                                              
                "partitions": {                                                                                        
                    "sda1": {                                                                                          
                        "sectors": "497664",                                                                           
                        "sectorsize": 512,                                                                             
                        "size": "243.00 MB",                                                                           
                        "start": "2048"                                                                                
                    },                                                                                                 
                    "sda2": {                                                                                          
                        "sectors": "2",                                                                                
                        "sectorsize": 512,                                                                             
                        "size": "1.00 KB",                                                                             
                        "start": "501758"                                                                              
                    },                                                                                                 
                },                                                                                                     
                "removable": "0",                                                                                      
                "rotational": "1",                                                                                     
                "scheduler_mode": "cfq",                                                                               
                "sectors": "167772160",                                                                                
                "sectorsize": "512",                                                                                   
                "size": "80.00 GB",                                                                                    
                "support_discard": "0",                                                                                
                "vendor": "ATA"                                                                                        
            },                                                                                                         
            "sr0": {                                                                                                   
                "holders": [],                                                                                         
                "host": "IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)",                           
                "model": "CD-ROM",                                                                                     
                "partitions": {},                                                                                      
                "removable": "1",                                                                                      
                "rotational": "1",                                                                                     
                "scheduler_mode": "cfq",                                                                               
                "sectors": "2097151",                                                                                  
                "sectorsize": "512",                                                                                   
                "size": "1024.00 MB",                                                                                  
                "support_discard": "0",                                                                                
                "vendor": "VBOX"                                                                                       
            },                                                                                                         
            "sr1": {                                                                                                   
                "holders": [],                                                                                         
                "host": "IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)",                           
                "model": "CD-ROM",                                                                                     
                "partitions": {},                                                                                      
                "removable": "1",                                                                                      
                "rotational": "1",                                                                                     
                "scheduler_mode": "cfq",                                                                               
                "sectors": "2097151",                                                                                  
                "sectorsize": "512",                                                                                   
                "size": "1024.00 MB",                                                                                  
                "support_discard": "0",                                                                                
                "vendor": "VBOX"                                                                                       
            }                                                                                                          
        },                                                                                                             
        "ansible_distribution": "Ubuntu",                                                                              
        "ansible_distribution_release": "precise",                                                                     
        "ansible_distribution_version": "12.04",                                                                       
        "ansible_domain": "",                                                                                          
        "ansible_eth0": {                                                                                              
            "active": true,                                                                                            
            "device": "eth0",                                                                                          
            "ipv4": {                                                                                                  
                "address": "10.0.2.15",                                                                                
                "netmask": "255.255.255.0",                                                                            
                "network": "10.0.2.0"                                                                                  
            },                                                                                                         
            "ipv6": [                                                                                                  
                {                                                                                                      
                    "address": "fe80::a00:27ff:fe12:9698",                                                             
                    "prefix": "64",                                                                                    
                    "scope": "link"                                                                                    
                }                                                                                                      
            ],                                                                                                         
            "macaddress": "08:00:27:12:96:98",                                                                         
            "module": "e1000",                                                                                         
            "mtu": 1500,                                                                                               
            "type": "ether"                                                                                            
        },                                                                                                             
        "ansible_eth1": {                                                                                              
            "active": true,                                                                                            
            "device": "eth1",                                                                                          
            "ipv4": {                                                                                                  
                "address": "192.168.10.10",                                                                            
                "netmask": "255.255.255.0",                                                                            
                "network": "192.168.10.0"                                                                              
            },                                                                                                         
            "ipv6": [                                                                                                  
                {                                                                                                      
                    "address": "fe80::a00:27ff:fe74:1330",                                                             
                    "prefix": "64",                                                                                    
                    "scope": "link"                                                                                    
                }                                                                                                      
            ],                                                                                                         
            "macaddress": "08:00:27:74:13:30",                                                                         
            "module": "e1000",                                                                                         
            "mtu": 1500,                                                                                               
            "type": "ether"                                                                                            
        },                                                                                                             
        "ansible_form_factor": "Other",                                                                                
        "ansible_fqdn": "scdev",                                                                                       
        "ansible_hostname": "scdev",                                                                                   
        "ansible_interfaces": [                                                                                        
            "lo",                                                                                                      
            "eth1",                                                                                                    
            "eth0"                                                                                                     
        ],                                                                                                             
        "ansible_kernel": "3.2.0-23-generic-pae",                                                                      
        "ansible_lo": {                                                                                                
            "active": true,                                                                                            
            "device": "lo",                                                                                            
            "ipv4": {                                                                                                  
                "address": "127.0.0.1",                                                                                
                "netmask": "255.0.0.0",                                                                                
                "network": "127.0.0.0"                                                                                 
            },                                                                                                         
            "ipv6": [                                                                                                  
                {                                                                                                      
                    "address": "::1",                                                                                  
                    "prefix": "128",                                                                                   
                    "scope": "host"                                                                                    
                }                                                                                                      
            ],                                                                                                         
            "mtu": 16436,                                                                                              
            "type": "loopback"                                                                                         
        },                                                                                                             
        "ansible_lsb": {                                                                                               
            "codename": "precise",                                                                                     
            "description": "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS",                                                                         
            "id": "Ubuntu",                                                                                            
            "major_release": "12",                                                                                     
            "release": "12.04"                                                                                         
        },                                                                                                             
        "ansible_machine": "i686",                                                                                     
        "ansible_memfree_mb": 23,                                                                                      
        "ansible_memtotal_mb": 369,                                                                                    
        "ansible_mounts": [                                                                                            
            {                                                                                                          
                "device": "/dev/mapper/precise32-root",                                                                
                "fstype": "ext4",                                                                                      
                "mount": "/",                                                                                          
                "options": "rw,errors=remount-ro",                                                                     
                "size_available": 77685088256,                                                                         
                "size_total": 84696281088                                                                              
            },                                                                                                         
            {                                                                                                          
                "device": "/dev/sda1",                                                                                 
                "fstype": "ext2",                                                                                      
                "mount": "/boot",                                                                                      
                "options": "rw",                                                                                       
                "size_available": 201044992,                                                                           
                "size_total": 238787584                                                                                
            },                                                                                                         
            {                                                                                                          
                "device": "/vagrant",                                                                                  
                "fstype": "vboxsf",                                                                                    
                "mount": "/vagrant",                                                                                   
                "options": "uid=1000,gid=1000,rw",                                                                     
                "size_available": 42013151232,                                                                         
                "size_total": 484145360896                                                                             
            }                                                                                                          
        ],                                                                                                             
        "ansible_os_family": "Debian",                                                                                 
        "ansible_pkg_mgr": "apt",                                                                                      
        "ansible_processor": [                                                                                         
            "Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5300  @ 2.60GHz"                                                          
        ],                                                                                                             
        "ansible_processor_cores": "NA",                                                                               
        "ansible_processor_count": 1,                                                                                  
        "ansible_product_name": "VirtualBox",                                                                          
        "ansible_product_serial": "NA",                                                                                
        "ansible_product_uuid": "NA",                                                                                  
        "ansible_product_version": "1.2",                                                                              
        "ansible_python_version": "2.7.3", 
        "ansible_selinux": false, 
        "ansible_swapfree_mb": 766, 
        "ansible_swaptotal_mb": 767, 
        "ansible_system": "Linux", 
        "ansible_system_vendor": "innotek GmbH", 
        "ansible_user_id": "neves", 
        "ansible_userspace_architecture": "i386", 
        "ansible_userspace_bits": "32", 
        "ansible_virtualization_role": "guest", 
        "ansible_virtualization_type": "virtualbox"
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

The current documentation now has a complete chapter about [*Discovering variables: facts and magic variables*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html).

Comment: this is not complete list of variables.

Comment: to use the command on a single IP/host not given in an inventory, invoke: `ansible <ip> -m setup -i <ip>,` - don't forget the comma at the end to make it a list and hence an inventory.

Comment: Is there no documented list of what each of these things *are*? Of what things *might* appear in the list on various servers, even though they don't show up on the one(s) you're hitting?

Comment: nope! Isn't that too funny. And annoying. Anyways, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/34263).

Comment: The ansible docs are pretty weak in some areas, I think it's probably off-putting to newbs. I mean, I can't make head-nor-tail of using tags with include_tasks, seems to result in odd behaviour

Answer (score 74):

```
ansible -m setup hostname
```

Only gets the facts gathered by the setup module.

Gilles Cornu posted a [template trick](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-project/IVUwp9195Ek/HZ3QXvf6s1sJ) to list all variables for a specific host.

Template (later called *dump_variables*):

```
HOSTVARS (ANSIBLE GATHERED, group_vars, host_vars) :

{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] | to_yaml }}

PLAYBOOK VARS:

{{ vars | to_yaml }}
```

Playbook to use it:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - template:
      src: templates/dump_variables
      dest: /tmp/ansible_variables
  - fetch:
      src: /tmp/ansible_variables
      dest: "{{inventory_hostname}}_ansible_variables"
```

After that you have a dump of all variables on every host, and a copy of each text dump file on your local workstation in your tmp folder. If you don't want local copies, you can remove the fetch statement.

This includes gathered facts, host variables and group variables.
Therefore you see ansible default variables like *group_names*, *inventory_hostname*, *ansible_ssh_host* and so on.

Comment: This is the correct answer - the other upvoted answers don't get you a complete list of variables available to you.

Comment: this one doesn't get you complete list either.

Comment: Can you give an example of what is missing?

Answer (score 36):

There are 3 sources of variables in Ansible:

1. Variables gathered from facts. You can get them by running command: `ansible -m setup hostname`
2. Built-in (pre-defined) Ansible variables (AKA 'magic' variables). They are  documented in Ansible documentation: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts
   Here is the list extracted from Ansible 1.9 documentation:

   - group_names
   - groups
   - inventory_hostname
   - ansible_hostname
   - inventory_hostname_short
   - play_hosts
   - delegate_to
   - inventory_dir
   - inventory_file
3. Variables passed to ansible via command line. But obviously you know what they are

Comment: The template trick in the post above by Enno errors out for me on v2.2.1. The list you provided under 2 had what I needed, was just hard to find manually. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the only complete answer, as the OP didn't ask for only the variables that begin with ansible_, they asked for "all available variables". The magic variables are not even referenced let alone included in the FAQ answer. Since this answer was written, there are additional useful magic variables such as `role_path` - it is worth visiting the link provided to see the list for the current version of Ansible. Be aware that ansible develops rapidly and repo versions for Debian and its children are quite old. Check the version you have installed against the docs carefully.

Answer (score 17):

I use this simple playbook:

```
---
# vars.yml
#
# Shows the value of all variables/facts.
#
# Example:
#
#   ansible-playbook vars.yml -e 'hosts=localhost'
#
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - fail: "You must specify a value for `hosts` variable - e.g.: ansible-playbook vars.yml -e 'hosts=localhost'"
      when: hosts is not defined

- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=vars
    - debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```

Comment: and you still will not get complete list of variables using it.

Comment: can you elaborate on your comment please ?

Comment: Upvoting this fix, because sometimes (particularly with cloud inventories), `ansible -m setup` doesn't do the trick and you need to get this info from a playbook.

Answer (score 10):

There is lot of variables defined as Facts -- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts

```
"ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
    "REDACTED IP ADDRESS"
],
"ansible_all_ipv6_addresses": [
    "REDACTED IPV6 ADDRESS"
],
"ansible_architecture": "x86_64",
"ansible_bios_date": "09/20/2012",
"ansible_bios_version": "6.00",
"ansible_cmdline": {
    "BOOT_IMAGE": "/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic",
    "quiet": true,
    "ro": true,
    "root": "UUID=4195bff4-e157-4e41-8701-e93f0aec9e22",
    "splash": true
},
"ansible_date_time": {
    "date": "2013-10-02",
    "day": "02",
    "epoch": "1380756810",
    "hour": "19",
    "iso8601": "2013-10-02T23:33:30Z",
    "iso8601_micro": "2013-10-02T23:33:30.036070Z",
    "minute": "33",
    "month": "10",
    "second": "30",
    "time": "19:33:30",
    "tz": "EDT",
    "year": "2013"
},
"ansible_default_ipv4": {
    "address": "REDACTED",
    "alias": "eth0",
    "gateway": "REDACTED",
    "interface": "eth0",
    "macaddress": "REDACTED",
    "mtu": 1500,
    "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
    "network": "REDACTED",
    "type": "ether"
},
"ansible_default_ipv6": {},
"ansible_devices": {
    "fd0": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "",
        "model": null,
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "1",
        "rotational": "1",
        "scheduler_mode": "deadline",
        "sectors": "0",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "0.00 Bytes",
        "support_discard": "0",
        "vendor": null
    },
    "sda": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev 01)",
        "model": "VMware Virtual S",
        "partitions": {
            "sda1": {
                "sectors": "39843840",
                "sectorsize": 512,
                "size": "19.00 GB",
                "start": "2048"
            },
            "sda2": {
                "sectors": "2",
                "sectorsize": 512,
                "size": "1.00 KB",
                "start": "39847934"
            },
            "sda5": {
                "sectors": "2093056",
                "sectorsize": 512,
                "size": "1022.00 MB",
                "start": "39847936"
            }
        },
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "scheduler_mode": "deadline",
        "sectors": "41943040",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "20.00 GB",
        "support_discard": "0",
        "vendor": "VMware,"
    },
    "sr0": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)",
        "model": "VMware IDE CDR10",
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "1",
        "rotational": "1",
        "scheduler_mode": "deadline",
        "sectors": "2097151",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "1024.00 MB",
        "support_discard": "0",
        "vendor": "NECVMWar"
    }
},
"ansible_distribution": "Ubuntu",
"ansible_distribution_release": "precise",
"ansible_distribution_version": "12.04",
"ansible_domain": "",
"ansible_env": {
    "COLORTERM": "gnome-terminal",
    "DISPLAY": ":0",
    "HOME": "/home/mdehaan",
    "LANG": "C",
    "LESSCLOSE": "/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s",
    "LESSOPEN": "| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s",
    "LOGNAME": "root",
    "LS_COLORS": "rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:",
    "MAIL": "/var/mail/root",
    "OLDPWD": "/root/ansible/docsite",
    "PATH": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
    "PWD": "/root/ansible",
    "SHELL": "/bin/bash",
    "SHLVL": "1",
    "SUDO_COMMAND": "/bin/bash",
    "SUDO_GID": "1000",
    "SUDO_UID": "1000",
    "SUDO_USER": "mdehaan",
    "TERM": "xterm",
    "USER": "root",
    "USERNAME": "root",
    "XAUTHORITY": "/home/mdehaan/.Xauthority",
    "_": "/usr/local/bin/ansible"
},
"ansible_eth0": {
    "active": true,
    "device": "eth0",
    "ipv4": {
        "address": "REDACTED",
        "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
        "network": "REDACTED"
    },
    "ipv6": [
        {
            "address": "REDACTED",
            "prefix": "64",
            "scope": "link"
        }
    ],
    "macaddress": "REDACTED",
    "module": "e1000",
    "mtu": 1500,
    "type": "ether"
},
"ansible_form_factor": "Other",
"ansible_fqdn": "ubuntu2.example.com",
"ansible_hostname": "ubuntu2",
"ansible_interfaces": [
    "lo",
    "eth0"
],
"ansible_kernel": "3.5.0-23-generic",
"ansible_lo": {
    "active": true,
    "device": "lo",
    "ipv4": {
        "address": "127.0.0.1",
        "netmask": "255.0.0.0",
        "network": "127.0.0.0"
    },
    "ipv6": [
        {
            "address": "::1",
            "prefix": "128",
            "scope": "host"
        }
    ],
    "mtu": 16436,
    "type": "loopback"
},
"ansible_lsb": {
    "codename": "precise",
    "description": "Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS",
    "id": "Ubuntu",
    "major_release": "12",
    "release": "12.04"
},
"ansible_machine": "x86_64",
"ansible_memfree_mb": 74,
"ansible_memtotal_mb": 991,
"ansible_mounts": [
    {
        "device": "/dev/sda1",
        "fstype": "ext4",
        "mount": "/",
        "options": "rw,errors=remount-ro",
        "size_available": 15032406016,
        "size_total": 20079898624
    }
],
"ansible_nodename": "ubuntu2.example.com",
"ansible_os_family": "Debian",
"ansible_pkg_mgr": "apt",
"ansible_processor": [
    "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         860  @ 2.80GHz"
],
"ansible_processor_cores": 1,
"ansible_processor_count": 1,
"ansible_processor_threads_per_core": 1,
"ansible_processor_vcpus": 1,
"ansible_product_name": "VMware Virtual Platform",
"ansible_product_serial": "REDACTED",
"ansible_product_uuid": "REDACTED",
"ansible_product_version": "None",
"ansible_python_version": "2.7.3",
"ansible_selinux": false,
"ansible_ssh_host_key_dsa_public": "REDACTED KEY VALUE"
"ansible_ssh_host_key_ecdsa_public": "REDACTED KEY VALUE"
"ansible_ssh_host_key_rsa_public": "REDACTED KEY VALUE"
"ansible_swapfree_mb": 665,
"ansible_swaptotal_mb": 1021,
"ansible_system": "Linux",
"ansible_system_vendor": "VMware, Inc.",
"ansible_user_id": "root",
"ansible_userspace_architecture": "x86_64",
"ansible_userspace_bits": "64",
"ansible_virtualization_role": "guest",
"ansible_virtualization_type": "VMware"
```

Answer (score 10):

The [`debug` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/debug_module.html) can be used to analyze variables. Be careful running the following command. In our setup it generates 444709 lines with 16MB:

```
ansible -m debug -a 'var=hostvars' localhost
```

*I am not sure but it might be necessary to enable facts caching.*

If you need just one host use the host name as a key for the `hostvars` hash:

```
ansible -m debug -a 'var=hostvars.localhost' localhost
```

This command will display also [group](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#group-variables) and [host](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#host-variables) variables.

Answer (score 4):

Note the official docs on connection configuration variables or "behavioral" variables - which aren't listed in host vars, appears to be [List of Behavioral Inventory Parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters) in the [Inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#inventory) documentation.

P.S. The `sudo` option is undocumented there (yes its `sudo` not `ansible_sudo` as you'd expect ...) and probably a couple more aren't, but thats best doc I've found on em.

Answer (score 1):

Some variables are not available on every host, e.g. `ansible_domain` and `domain`. If the situation needs to be debugged, I login to the server and issue:

```
user@server:~$ ansible -m setup localhost | grep domain
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
    "ansible_domain": "prd.example.com",
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been answered already, but I feel like there are a whole other set of pre-defined variables not covered by the ansible_* facts. [This documentation page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_keywords.html) covers the *directives* (variables that modify Ansible's behavior), which I was looking for when I came across this page.

This includes some common and some specific use-case directives:

- become: Controls privilege escalation (sudo)
- delegate_to: run task on another host (like running on localhost)
- serial: allows you to run a play across a specific number/percentage of hosts before moving onto next set

Comment: Try to provide some of the important variables here and use the link for reference so if for any reason the link breaks your answer will be still useful.

Comment: I added some examples. It's hard to list "important" variables since that varies a lot based on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: The documentation link you provided is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/f500/ansible-dumpall
FYI: this github project shows you how to list 90% of variables across all hosts. I find it more globally useful than single host commands. The README includes instructions for building a simple inventory report. It's even more valuable to run this at the end of a playbook to see all the Facts. To also debug Task behaviour use register:

The result is missing a few items:
- included YAML file variables
- extra-vars
- a number of the Ansible internal vars described here: [Ansible Behavioural Params](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters)