# How to get facts at each command in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Ansible get facts only at start. But i need check facts at each commands.
For example:

I need create a directory, after that i need put file to this directory. But ansible get fact 'dir doesn't exist' at start, create dir and at next step fact still FALSE and ansible skip this step =( And do this step only after second run.

I'll try `setup` after all steps to gathering facts again but it doesn't work.

I do it like this:

```
 - stat: path=/etc/zabbix/scripts/rabbitmq
   register: rmqscriptdir

 - name: Create scripts dir if not exist
   when: rmqscriptdir.stat.exists == False
   shell: mkdir /etc/zabbix/scripts/rabbitmq

 - name: Gathering facts again
   setup:

 - name: Set owner and permissions to rabbitmq directory
   when: rmqscriptdir.stat.exists == True
   file: path=/etc/zabbix/scripts/rabbitmq owner=zabbix group=root mode=0750


 - stat: path=/etc/zabbix/scripts/rabbitmq/api.py
   register: rmqscript_api

 - name: Create api.py if not exist 
   when: rmqscript_api.stat.exists == False and rmqscriptdir.stat.exists == True
   shell: cd /etc/zabbix/scripts/rabbitmq; wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jasonmcintosh/rabbitmq-zabbix/master/scripts/rabbitmq/api.py

 - name: Gathering facts again
   setup:

 - name: Set owner and permissions to api.py
   when: rmqscript_api.stat.exists == True
   file: path=/etc/zabbix/scripts/rabbitmq/api.py owner=zabbix group=root mode=0755
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what the `setup` module does. By registering a value it does not become a fact that will be reloaded by the `setup` module when run again. Your registered value stays the same. If you want to check again if a path exists you do not need to re-run the `setup` module, but the `stats` module and again register its output.

But anyway, the idea of Ansible is actually to not manually check if every task should be executed or not. That is something Ansible takes care for you, Ansible in general is indepotent, meaning it will have the same result no matter how many times you run the play.

Here is a cleaned up version, which creates a folder and downloads the file. If the folder already exists, the 1st task will do nothing. If the file `api.py` already exists, the 2nd task will do nothing.

```
- name: Create scripts dir if not exist
  file:
    path: /etc/zabbix/scripts/rabbitmq
    state: directory
    owner: zabbix
    group: root
    mode: 0750

- name: Create api.py if not exist
  get_url:
    url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jasonmcintosh/rabbitmq-zabbix/master/scripts/rabbitmq/api.py
    dest: /etc/zabbix/scripts/rabbitmq/api.py
    owner: zabbix
    group: root
    mode: 0755
```

---

PS: If you want to see which values are reloaded by the `setup` module, you can register its output and show it in a debug task, like so:

```
- setup:
  register: all_server_facts

- debug:
    var: all_server_facts
```

This only contains server facts, info about cpu, hard drives, network etc. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839535/2753241) for an example output.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Before ansible i work with puppet, it run a tasks randomly and want to check all dependency at each commands. Can i register stats to previously registered variable?

Comment: You can override a previously registered variable. Is that what you mean?

Comment: And last question. Can i use keyword 'name' under section 'file' or 'get_url'?

Comment: You mean to name your tasks? Then yes. I added it to my example above.

Comment: No. I need to know if directory exist, than i can create file in directory, else i need create directory, then create file. But if i understand correctly, ansible run consequentially and if i create directory at beginning of task, i can be sure -- dir exist in next steps of task?

Comment: Yes, exactly, all tasks are executed in the order they are defined.